# containsKey() is getting id but not entering in for loop

Tags: apex, trigger

```
Map <Id, Contact> cntMap = new Map <Id, Contact> ([Select id, AccountId from Contact where id = '0032800001JpHgmGGF']);
System.debug('coming::' + cntMap); // getting AccountId
for (Contact x: cntMap.values()) {
    System.debug('cntMaps::' + cntMap.containsKey(x.AccountId)); // getting false 
    if (cntMap.containsKey(x.AccountId)) {
        System.debug('Yes it has');
        Contact d = cntMap.get(x.AccountId);
    } else {
        System.debug('jjj::' + x.AccountId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you store Write your map as follows:-

```
Map <Id, Contact> cntMap = new Map <Id, Contact> ([Select id, AccountId from Contact where id = '0032800001JpHgmGGF']);
```

Here the key is id of the Contact, Not the id of the Contact.account. That's why your if part returning false.

you need to change your code as follows:-

```
 Map <Id, Contact> cntMap = new Map <Id, Contact> ([Select id, AccountId from Contact limit 2]);
System.debug('coming::' + cntMap); // getting AccountId
for (Contact x: cntMap.values()) {
    System.debug('cntMaps::' + cntMap.get(x.id).Accountid);  
    if (cntMap.get(x.id).Accountid!=null) {
        System.debug('Yes it has');
        Contact d = cntMap.get(x.AccountId);
    } else {
        System.debug('jjj::' + x.AccountId);
    }
}
```

**containsKey(key)**

> Returns true if the map contains a mapping for the specified key.

```
 Map<String, String> colorCodes = new Map<String, String>();

colorCodes.put('Red', 'FF0000');
colorCodes.put('Blue', '0000A0');

Boolean contains = colorCodes.containsKey('Blue');
System.assertEquals(true, contains);
```

Comment: Hi sanket, thanks for ur reply but even "AccountId" is also field of contact, which has a value.

Comment: Yes, But you are checking for the key using containskey() function and your map have Contactid as key, not the accountid. That's why you need to check for values using cntMap.get(x.id).Accountid.

Comment: In your map you are storing contactIds... while accessing you are trying to access account ids.its wrong.what you have store that you have to access it.